# WPF invokes value converter with empty string

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox bound to a list of values, for the sake of this example, a simple array of `int`s. The control has a custom `ItemTemplate` assigned to format its elements, which, in turn, uses an `IValueConverter` for some of its operation.

There's a particular case where this fails: If the `ComboBox` has an element selected, and the list of items changes, the converter's `Convert` is invoked with an empty string, which is most definitely not one of the values bound to my control. (Note that I'm *not* talking about the `ConvertBack` method.)

My questions would be:

1. Why is the `IValueConverter` being invoked with `value` being an empty string (`""`) when no string is ever bound to the control?
2. What are some non-hacky solutions to the problem? (I could just place `if (value is "") return null;` in the converter, and it seems to make the error go away, but I feel like it's treating the symptoms, not the cause.)

---

The problem can be reproduced with a simple WPF project (`dotnet new wpf`) containing only these 3 files (the problem is present on both the Framework and Core versions of .NET):

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Selector" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={x:Static local:Converter.Instance}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Replace" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace test
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Selector.ItemsSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        }

      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         Selector.ItemsSource = new int[] { -1, -2, -3 };
      }

      [STAThread]
      public static void Main(String[] args)
      {
         new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
      }
   }
}
```

And finally Converter.cs:

```c#
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace test
{
    class Converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static Converter Instance { get; } = new Converter();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Debug.Assert(value is int);

            return (2 * (int) value).ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

These 3 files form a minimal example that exhibits this behavior. If the "replace" button is clicked *without* selecting anything from the ComboBox first, the program runs fine. If, however, any value is selected in the ComboBox before clicking the button, the assertion in the converter fails, because upon clicking the button, the converter is passed a `value` of `""`.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried your code when a currently selected item is not in the newly set item source the selected item should be changed right? So they change the selected item to "". That is the selected item you see in the initial state of the app running.

For a fact, if you keep the selected item in the new item source then it won't execute convert with value "". 
Consider your initial item source is

```
Selector.ItemsSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Now you select the second element which is displayed as 4 in your combo box and click replace to run this.

```
 Selector.ItemsSource = new int[]{ -1, 2, -3 };
```

Then it won't execute the converter with value "".

Here the problem is the selected item is not present in the new item source so the Combobox is selecting its default value and your Combobox will behave like the exact way you started your application.

Comment: In the application this error came about it does not make any sense to keep the previous item in the new list.